# uiscrollview inside of a uiview does not work

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode4.2

a `UIScrollView` works just fine by it's self (in IB). However, once you put the `UIScrollView` inside of a `UIVIew` in IB, it no longer works. I'm doing this with no subclassing so what's the deal?

## Answer

- You have to make sure `Autoresize Subviews` is checked on the containing `UIView`.
- The next part is a bit of a hack. You need to assign a new `frame` to the containing `UIView` as well. However, the new `frame` **CANNOT** be the pre-existing size of your `UIView`. It must be a different size for this to work.

If you want the size contained on your `UIView` in `InterfaceBuilder` then you need to do something like this:

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
self.frame = [put your desired rect size here];
```

Comment: what kind of problem are you facing after putting scrollview in uiview? Are you not able to scroll?

Comment: @PiyushKashyap Correct. It's almost like the UIView is stealing all the touch events..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried returning `NO` in `touchesBegan` if the touch falls inside your scroll view's frame?

Edit:
Make sure you set the scroll view's content size (`[[self scrollView] setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,480)];` - the values do not matter) and *make sure you check "Bounce Horizontally" and/or "Bounce Vertically" (depending on which you want) **as well as "Bounces":***

[image: Bounce Settings Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, my bad - cocos2d has equivalent methods that allow you to do that, but not UIKit.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all stuff I had already done. Oddly enough, a TextView scrolls inside the scrollview. crazy. I'm going back to the drawing board..

Comment: Have you made sure it is at the front? (Editor>Arrange>Send to Front)

Comment: It's the only child, so "Send to Front" is grayed out.

Comment: Wow. For whatever reason, I had to have `Autoresize Subviews` checked and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set contentsize property of UiScrollView like this

```
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,860);
```

Comment: Already tried that, no success. Even without that I'm thinking that the scrollview should *at least* bounce.

Comment: Won't scroll without that, sadly.